# How to send dynamic comma separated string value in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I would like to send string containing comma separated values in url.

After clicking on Add button i'm adding input text full name value to text area. 
I want to send all the value added in text area which is separated by comma in url.

```
 <textarea name="txtAttendeeNames" id="txtAttendeeNames" rows="5" cols="38" class="txt" readonly=""></textarea>
```

I created below url to pass values in url

```
 http://shopping.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=TSTDRV945986&n=1&buyid=172,1,custcol_name_of_attendees|'+ document.getElementById('txtAttendeeNames').value+'|custcol_event_name|'+ document.getElementById('hdEventName').value+';
```

The problem is that text area field has values like value1,value2,value3. When i am adding document.getElementById('txtAttendeeNames').value in url it is separating value and i am not able to create url.

Is there any other way i can pass these comma separated dynamic values in comma format?

Comment: You should use POST method, instead sending data in Url

Comment: yes im doing that but im creating this url externally so what would be the syntax

Comment: otherwise use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) i.e.  `encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtAttendeeNames').value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following...

```
var Parameters= {
    IDs: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
};
var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(Parameters));
http://shopping.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=TSTDRV945986&n=1&buyid=data;
```

Answer (score 0):

var param = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("txtAttendeeNames").value);

> **Example** 
> Encode a URI:
>
> var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"; var
>   res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
>
> **The result of res will be**:
>   http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab

[Click](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can send it simply, here i use lodash to create comma separated value

```
       var buyIds = _.map(selectedProducts, 'id').join(',');
       http://shopping.com/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=TSTDRV945986&n=1&buyid=buyIds
```